# How to split a string which is a numbered list

Tags: regex, ruby, split

I have a string like this

```
20. Kyoto, Japan19. Rijeka, Croatia18. Panama17. Rabat, Morocco16. The British Virgin Islands15. Frisian Islands, Denmark14. Qingdao, China13. Lebanon12. Portland, Maine, US11. Dakar, Senegal10. Egadi Islands, Sicily9. Paris, France8. Siargao, Philippines7. Galway, Ireland6. Kangaroo Island, Australia5. Salvador, Brazil4. Armenia3. Kyrgyzstan2. Plymouth, UK1. Pakistan19. THE TURKISH RIVIERA18. PERTH, WESTERN AUSTRALIA17. SINGAPORE16. THE SCOTTISH HIGHLANDS15. St Barth’s,Caribbean14. Mozambique13. Mumbai12. The Peloponnese, Greece11. Tahiti10. Namibia9. Patagonia8. Arles, France7. Chengdu, China6. Egypt5. Transylvania, Romania4. TASMANIA, AUSTRALIA3. New Orleans2. Valle de Guadalupe1. Matera, Italy
```

How would I split this by the list number? Can this be done preserving the number or am I better off adding the number later?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Seems like the data got corrupted. Where does that string come from in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to SO! See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)". Your data looks like you scraped it from a page, but did it wrong, and now need to take it apart again. If that's true, then your question shouldn't be about splitting it, it should be about the right way to scrape text. Also, we need to see your effort toward solving this. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Whenever you give an example in an SO question you should: 1) make the example as brief as possible while retaining all essential elements; write all inputs as valid Ruby objects, in part so that readers can cut and paste (strings, for example, are surrounded with quotes); 3 assign a variable to each input so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them; and 4) show your desired result (as a Ruby objects)...

Comment: ... Here you might write `str = "20. Kyoto, Japan19. Rijeka, Croatia18. Panama17. Rabat, Morocco"` with the desired result being `["20. Kyoto, Japan", "19. Rijeka, Croatia", "18. Panama", "17. Rabat, Morocco"]` or perhaps `[["20", "Kyoto, Japan"], ["19", "Rijeka, Croatia"], ["18", "Panama"], ["17", "Rabat, Morocco"]]`, whatever you want.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question, even though it has been closed. If you clarify it, it may be re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

If you are confident there are no digits save for item numbers, it’s easy. `String#scan` for *number* → *dot* → *spaces* → *not numbers*.

```rb
str.scan(/(\d+)\.\s+(\D+)/)
#⇒ [["20", "Kyoto, Japan"],
#   ["19", "Rijeka, Croatia"],
#   ["18", "Panama"],
#   ["17", "Rabat, Morocco"]
#   ....]
```

Comment: This is a perfect example for using `scan` with a regular expression that has capture groups. You can of course add `.to_h` at the end to get a hash.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "20. Kyoto, Japan19. Rijeka, Croatia18. Panama17. Rabat, Morocco"
```

```
r1 = /(?<=\D)(?=\d)|\. +/
h = Hash[*str.split(r1)]
  #=> {"20"=>"Kyoto, Japan", "19"=>"Rijeka, Croatia", "18"=>"Panama",
  #    "17"=>"Rabat, Morocco"}
```

Then perhaps:

```
r2 = /\S+\z/
r3 = /[^,]+/
g = h.transform_values do |v|
      { country: v[r2], city: v.include?(',') ? v[r3] : '' }
end
  #=> {"20"=>{:country=>"Japan", :city=>"Kyoto"},
  #    "19"=>{:country=>"Croatia", :city=>"Rijeka"},
  #    "18"=>{:country=>"Panama", :city=>""},
  #    "17"=>{:country=>"Morocco", :city=>"Rabat"}}
```

See[Hash::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). If `a = [1,2]`, `Hash[*a]` is the same as `Hash[1,2]`.

The three regular expressions can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make them self-documenting:

```
r1 = /
     (?<=\D)  # match is to be preceded by any char other than
              # a digit (positive lookbehind)
     (?=\d)   # match is to be followed by a digit
              # (positive lookahead)
     |        # or
     \.[ ]+   # match a period followed by one or more spaces
     /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Notice that `(?<=\D)(?=\d)` causes the string to be split *between* two adjacent characters. In free-spacing mode spaces are removed before the regex is parsed, which is why spaces intended to be part of the regex must be protected (e.g., write `[ ]` `\`, `[[:space:]]` or `\p{Space}`).

```
r2 = / 
     \S+  # match one or more characters other than whitespace
     \z   # match the end of the string
     /x
```

```
r3 = /
     [^,] # match any character other than a comma...
     +    # ...one or more times 
     /x
```

Comment: Your first example has a syntax error.